# targeting inner content on hover

Tags: html, css

I have the following button and code

html

```
    <div id="top-btn">
      <a href=""><i>button</i></a>
      <div id="top-btn-BG"></div>
    </div>
```

css

```
#top-btn a {
  z-index: 999;
  padding: 30px 30px 25px 25px;
  color: #707070;
  bottom: 0; right: 0;
}

#top-btn a:hover+#top-btn-BG:after,#top-btn-BG:hover:after {
   border-color: transparent transparent #333 transparent;
}
```

This changes the background of #top-btn-BG when top-btn is hovered over. I want to change the color of #top-btn aswell, but have trouble targeting it

Comment: Please provide working code.

Comment: You can't select a parent with CSS. You have to place the hover on `top-btn`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like that:

```css
#top-btn a {
  z-index: 999;
  padding: 30px 30px 25px 25px;
  color: #707070;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}

#top-btn:hover #top-btn-BG {
  background-color: red;
}

#top-btn:hover a {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="top-btn" class="flex fade-in">
  <a href=""><i> link </i></a>
  <div id="top-btn-BG">ghjghjg</div>
</div>
```